# MODx mysql array sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, modx

I need to make a sorted list of filtered entries for MODx page. I have a several entries in db with 'table1' and columns 'id', 'name', 'someparam1' etc. I can print the whole list on the page with

```
$companies = $modx->getCollection('Company'); 
foreach($companies as $company) {
    $fields = $company->toArray();
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('showEntryTpl', $fields);
}
return $output;
```

but i still can't print the same list using [recommendation#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582932/php-sort-an-array-by-lastname-seperated-by-whitespace-in-modx) or [recommendation#2](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/xPDO20/Retrieving+Objects):
Example from MODx docs:

```
$c = $xpdo->newQuery('Box');
$c->innerJoin('BoxOwner','Owner'); // arguments are: className, alias
$c->where(array(
   'width' => 5,
   'Owner.user' => 2,
));
$c->sortby('name','ASC');
$c->limit(5);
$boxes = $xpdo->getCollection('Box',$c);
```

Using it this way

```
$sortingcriteria = 'id';

$s = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$s->sortby($sortingcriteria,'ASC');
$out = $modx->getCollection('Company',$s);

return $out;
```

doesn't work. How can I sort the list by chosen column and then filter it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Vasis and Sean Kimball for suggestions! This code pulls several records from db sorted in ASC/DESC order and filtered by some value:

```
$sortingcriteria = 'id';
$filter1 = 'free';
$s = $modx->newQuery('Company');
$s->sortby($sortingcriteria,'ASC');
$s->where(array(
   'pay_type' => $filter1,
));
$out = $modx->getCollection('Company',$s);
$output = '';
foreach ($out as $item) {
    $fields = $item->toArray();
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('showAllCompaniesTpl', $fields);
}

return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sortingcriteria = 'id';

$s = $modx->newQuery('Company'); // your mistake here. Need to use 'Company' instead 'modResource'
```

and then you can sort and filter your entries

```
$s->sortby($sortingcriteria,'ASC');
$s->where(array(
   'column_name1' => 5,
   'column_name2' => 2,
));
$out = $modx->getCollection('Company',$s);

$output = '';
foreach ($out as $item) {
    $output .= $item->get('column_name') . '<br/>';
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Unfortunately no positive result... Not with Company, nor with modResource. With my previous variant it prints at least 'Array' on the page. Still `$companies = $modx->getCollection('Company'); 
foreach($companies as $company) {
    $fields = $company->toArray();
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('showAllCompaniesTpl', $fields);
}

return $output;`
prints a list from db but unsorted.

Comment: 'Company' is a custom extension? Is modx aware of it? either registered in the system or included/required in your snippet?

Comment: Yes, this code is designed to work with custom table 'Company' and assumes that the package has already been connected with "addPackage". And this will not work if you do not replace 'column_name1', column_name2' and 'column_name' to the names of the columns that are actually in the table 'Company'.

Comment: Here is the code i'm trying to work with: `$sortingcriteria = 'id';
$company_filter = 'company3';
$s = $modx->newQuery('Company');
$s->sortby($sortingcriteria,'ASC');
$s->where(array(
   'company_name' => $company_filter,
));
$out = $modx->getCollection('Company',$s);
$output = '';
foreach ($out as $item) {
    $fields = $item->toArray();
    $output .= $modx->getChunk('showAllCompaniesTpl', $fields);
}It
return $output;` This prints one record from db. But I need several (using filter) and ordered by some value (chosen by user).